# upload image outside cakephp's webroot/img folder

Tags: php, cakephp, image-uploading

I am building a web application using CakePHP. I am using [meioupload](http://www.meiocodigo.com/projects/meioupload/) to upload the images. These images are successfully uploaded. I would like to separate the admin-app and public-app into, of course, two separate CakePHP applications. The problem is that I can't share the images that were uploaded into the public-app's webroot with the admin-app's webroot and vice versa. I am thinking about uploading these images into another folder outside those two apps. Am I on the right track? If I am, how can I do this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

using meioupload, it turn out that i can use relative path, so i do it like this:

```
public $actsAs = array(
    'MeioUpload' => array(
        'filename' => array(
            'dir' => '../../../path/to/outside/webroot',
            'create_directory' => true,
        )
    )
);
```

Answer (score 1):

One solution is to modify your script to upload your images to a "shared" directory which can be view by both applications. Or, if you're on a Linux-like OS, you could make this shared directory under the document root and have a symbolic link created between the directories that each application will call.

So APP1 and APP2 could both upload to `/var/sharedStuff`. APP1 is located at `/var/www/app1` and APP2 is located at `/var/www/app2` Both of these apps could have a directory that is symlinked to the sharedStuff directory. So `/var/www/app1/app/webroot/img/shared` and `/var/www/app2/app/webroot/img/shared` would both internally point to `/var/sharedStuff`. You could then reference these images from your application just as if they were placed in that `img/shared` directory. Again, You'd need to modify your upload script to make sure it uploads files to this shared directory (or symlink) and not in an exclusive one.

Just to let you know, CakePHP has built in functionality for creating your own admin interface. There are many tutorials out there. Just a Google search away. Separating them into two applications seems less than ideal.